# Sort javascript object on multiple keys order by alphabet

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

Here is my js object:

```
var data = [
    { id: 7, name: "test1", sector: "A01" },
    { id: 7, name: "test2", sector: "C03" },
    { id: 8, name: "test4", sector: "B02" },
    { id: 8, name: "test5", sector: "A01" },
    { id: 8, name: "test6", sector: "C03" },
    { id: 7, name: "test3", sector: "B02" },
];
```

I want to sort this object by id and then by sector as below:

```
7,test1,A01
7,test3,B02
7,test2,C03
8,test5,A01
8,test4,B02
8,test6,C03
```

I have tried [thenBy.js](https://github.com/Teun/thenBy.js/tree/master), the code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rx3AP/1523/) , but the result is

```
7,test1,A01
7,test2,C03
7,test3,B02
8,test4,B02
8,test5,A01
8,test6,C03
```

How to fix it ?

If you can't see the output please go to External Resources on the left-side panel and add the following link for Firebug: getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js

Comment: @RobertStettler I have used it in my code , list at second line.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a look at your fiddle, and you're trying to subtract strings, which will result in `NaN`s, which can't really be used for sorting.

If you try using `>` or `<` when comparing the strings, it'll work.

Example:

```
firstBy(function (v1, v2) { return v1.id < v2.id ? -1 : (v1.id > v2.id ? 1 : 0); })
  .thenBy(function (v1, v2) { return v1.sector > v2.sector; });
```

This will yeild the result you're seeking.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. The code is paste from thenby.js example that's why I don't notice about.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without the `firstBy().thenBy` construct by simply concatenating the strings. The argument to the `sort` function will look like this:

```
function (v1, v2) { return v1.id + v1.sector < v2.id + v2.sector ? -1 : (v1.id + v1.sector> v2.id + v2.sector ? 1 : 0); }
```

Here is the [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rx3AP/1524/).